# Converting jquery trigger to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Anybody help with converting a trigger on click in jquery to pure javascript pls. Code is

`$("#classone").click(function () { $("li").toggleClass("visible"); });`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure JavaScript, you could do it as

```
document.querySelector("#classone").addEventListener("click",
function() {


document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(elem) {
          elem.classList.toggle("visible");
        });
    });
```

(sry code formatting got screwed up)

Comment: Hi
I forgot to add classone part of it. Could you look again the question?

Comment: Throws  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: Solved it by carrying script under. Thanks so much

Comment: @EmreUnver Great! Please click the checkmark next to my answer to mark this question answered